# Passing a file from a second automator variable to applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to create an application that will take a pdf as input (drag and drop) and sends an email with a user choosen subject.

I have thus created an automator workflow that is almost working. The only part I am not getting is passing the dropped file to the applescript so that it will attach it within the mail

Can someone help me to sort this out ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Here you can download the zipped workflow
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=12980776511398698508

and here is the applescript at the end of the automator workflow. The problem has to do with passing the second item of input which should be a file contained in a automator variable

```
on run {input, parameters}

set theSubject to first item of input -- the subject
set myFiles to second item of input -- the file

set theContent to "" -- the content
set theAddress to "xxx@163.com" -- the receiver 
set theAttachmentFile to myFiles

tell application "Mail"
    set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}
    tell msg to make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}
    tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}
    send msg
end tell

end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input parameter in the script contains a list of all variables from the previous Automator Actions "Get variable", in the same order. but you need to make sure you only get the list of variables you're looking for. In your current Automator flow, select the action "get value of No_Fax" and select "ignore entry". then the flow will stack only No_Fax and Files in the input parameter. Item 1 of input will be No_Fax, item 2 will be the 1st file, item 3, the 2nd file ....